# Store URL Images into Integer Array

Tags: android

The following code is what I plan to do.

```
Integer[] imageId = {
    R.drawable.a
    R.drawable.b
    R.drawable.c
    R.drawable.d
};
```

I can store these images into a Integer array but what if I plan to store URL picture that download from internet into Integer Array.  Is that a way to do this?  Thank you

Comment: why will you use Integer[] to store URL . Use String array .

Comment: What are you trying to do? can you provide more information...?

Comment: Those Integers are representation of those resource image found in the res folder relative to `R` file. The image path is a string so you want to have an array of Strings rather.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not a correct way. Storing resource id of images(which is Integer) is totally different from storing image path (which is String). You can use, String array to store url path of images.

Example :

`String[] imageID = {
"http://www.somewhere.com/data/drugaddiction/logo.png",
"http://www.somewhere.com/data/drugaddiction/image.png"
};`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store a Url picture (which usually is a string) in an int array you have to parse that string (url of the picture) into an int:

```
Integer[] imageUrlsAndIds = {
    Integer.parseInt("some Url"),
    Integer.parseInt("an Url of a picture of a pretty girl"),
    Integer.parseInt("another Url from Internet"),
    R.drawable.a,
    R.drawable.b,
    R.drawable.c,
    R.drawable.d
}
```